# Keystore public/private key

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, encryption

I am currently busy with Androidkeystore public/private key encryption. I am capturing user data and before I upload it to firebase I want to encrypt it. I managed to do that with the help of this link https://dzone.com/articles/xamarin-android-asymmetric-encryption-without-any.

I captured user sign in credentials together with user data on a device and encrypted the data with the public key before I uploaded it to firebase. I then retrieve the data from firebase and successfully decrypted the data with the private key. Now, when I sign in on a different device I am unable to decrypt the data. Is this maybe because I don't have the key pair of the previous device?

As you can most probably notice is that I have little knowledge of this topic. Is there any possible way I can achieve the above matter.

Below is the code I use:
*Initialize the KeyStore*

```
 public PlatformEncryptionKeyHelper(Context context, string keyName)
       {
           _context = context;
           _keyName = keyName.ToLowerInvariant();

           _androidKeyStore = KeyStore.GetInstance(KEYSTORE_NAME);
           _androidKeyStore.Load(null);
       }
```

*Generate keypair*

```
var builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(_keyName, KeyStorePurpose.Encrypt | KeyStorePurpose.Decrypt)
.SetBlockModes(KeyProperties.BlockModeEcb)
.SetEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.EncryptionPaddingRsaPkcs1)
.SetRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false).SetKeySize(KeySize);

              keyGenerator.Initialize(builder.Build());
            }

            keyGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
```

*Get Public key*

```
public IKey GetPublicKey()
{
    if (!_androidKeyStore.ContainsAlias(_keyName))
        return null;

    return _androidKeyStore.GetCertificate(_keyName)?.PublicKey;
}
```

*Get Private Key*

```
public IKey GetPrivateKey()
{
    if (!_androidKeyStore.ContainsAlias(_keyName))
        return null;

    return _androidKeyStore.GetKey(_keyName, null);
}
```

*Usage*

```
_encryptionKeyHelper = new PlatformEncryptionKeyHelper(Application.Context, KeyStoreName);
_encryptionKeyHelper.CreateKeyPair();

_privateKey = _encryptionKeyHelper.GetPrivateKey();
_publicKey = _encryptionKeyHelper.GetPublicKey();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when I sign in on a different device I am unable to decrypt the data

Based on the code you seems to generate a new keypair for every device.  How do you imagine to decrypt any data with different keys? You would need to have the same private key or decryption key on every user's device to share the encrypted data.

In the asymmetric encryption you encrypt using the recipient's public key, so in theory you may share public keys between each other user's devices and the user could encrypt for different devices. But without more details and use cases it may or may not be feasible.

> I captured user sign in credentials together with user data

Capturing / keeping the user credentials is usually a very bad idea. Do not store the user credentials even encrypted. Sooner or later it will blow up, especially when admitting *that I have little knowledge of this topic* (that is a good step)